# Using induction on n that if n is odd, then an n-cycle can be written as a product of 3-cycles.

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups

Here n is greater than or equal to 4 and we are working in Sn.

The hint states that given an n-cycle delta, find a 3-cycle tau such that the product delta*tao is an (n-2) cycle.

I am having trouble finding tao that makes the n cycle a product of 3-cycles.

Answer (score 0):

IF the question has the condition that $n$ is odd (which is stated in the title of your question but not explicitly in your question) then what does this tell you about $\delta$ in terms of being odd or even. Then think about generating sets for $A_{n}$. If you have not done any generating sets for $A_{n}$ then think about just 2 transpositions and combining them as a single cycle. Be careful to consider all possibilities of the 2 transpositions.

Comment: Hint: $$(1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5)=(1\ 2\ 3)(3\ 4\ 5)$$ $$(1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6\ 7)=(1\ 2\ 3)(3\ 4\ 5)(5\ 6\ 7)$$